# Desugar Lua operators

Tags: lua, operators, syntactic-sugar, first-class-functions

Since Lua supports first-class functions, I'd like to know if you can desugar operators, like in many functional languages. E.g in OCaml you can do:

```
let x = (+) 3 5
```

The code above inits the variable `x` with the value `3 + 5`. Writing `(+)` is equivalent of having a local function that takes two parameters and returns their sum. `(+) 3 5` is calling this function with the two arguments `3` and `5`.
The motivation behinds this is that you can pass the operator directly to a function without having to wrapped it in a function before:

```
local t = {"ab", "d", "c" }
local function op_greaterthan (a,b) return a>b end
table.sort (t, op_greaterthan) --would like to write: table.sort (t, (>))
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if it's impossible, you can make your own function (`function add(a, b) return a + b end`)

Comment: Um, can you explain what that code actually does? Not everyone know what OCaml is.

Comment: Why would one desugar operators?

Comment: In many programming languages, operators are treated as functions. For example, `1+2` is literally equivalent to `add(1,2)`. He's asking for a function that is directly equivalent to `add`. `function(a,b)return a+b end` is indirectly equivalent, in that it requires a Lua function to be called before the actual operator is applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

The Lua interpreter is very small, and it "makes shortcuts" when dealing with operators; for the parser, they are simply not "functions".

If you try to use an operator without its params, like this:

```
f(+)
```

Then the interpreter will throw a syntax error.

Due to this implementation, you are limited to the options already discussed: either you use a wrapper function (such as `add`) or you pass in a string and so some kind of `eval`, as in jpjacobs' solution.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can (I don't see the point of it, and it will be slower, but it is possible):

```
do
    local mem={}
    function unsugar(op,a,b)

        if mem[op] then
            print('Fetched operation from memory')
            return mem[op](a,b)
        else
            local f=loadstring('local a,b=...; return a '..op..' b')
            mem[op]=f
            return f(a,b)
        end
    end
end
print(unsugar('+',1,2)) -- = 3
print(unsugar('%',5,3)) -- = 2
print(unsugar('%',5,3)) -- = Fetched operation from memory \n 2
```

**Edit**: Eliminated stray globals a and b, and put in memoizing to improve performance, by compiling each operation only once.

Comment: This still wraps it in a function.

Comment: Just a side note - you are missing a `local` in the function, this way unwanted globals `a` and `b` are created. Also, you should [memoize the compiled functions](http://www.lua.org/pil/17.1.html) for efficiency reasons.

Comment: @Deco: as kikito said, you cannot "desugar" operators. You have to create functions for operators yourself. It's not hard, take a look [at this Penlight "operator" module](https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight/blob/master/lua/pl/operator.lua).

Comment: Entirely true. Edited my post accordingly